# Show that the solution to this ODE grows without bound.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Let $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^+$ be a continuous function.

Consider the following differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(y + x\sin{x}),\ y(0)=0$$

Show that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}y = \infty$.

---

I looked at this for about an hour and got nothing. Hints would be nice, intuition would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $f(\eta)$ is positive definite therefore $\frac{dy}{dx} > 0$ for all $x$ which means that $y$ is monotonically increasing.  That's not enough to prove $y$ grows without bound since $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x^2}$ is also positive definite but $y$ does _not_ grow without bound.

Comment: Yeah, that's about as far as I got with my line of reasoning. It's such a weird problem, too, because I don't see what purpose the $x\sin{x}$ term even serves, so I'm stuck without a starting point.

Comment: Read my answer, the $x\sin x $ term is there to create an oscillation in $f $'s arguments so that $\lim_{x\to\infty}y'$ can't equal zero. Atleast that's what it appears to be if my logic is right.

Answer (score 4):

Assume otherwise that $y$ is bounded. The idea of proof is that under this (false) assumption, $y$ is guaranteed to increase at least as fast as of order $1/n$ near the point $x = n\pi$. Then the overall growth of $y$ is at least logarithmic, which will contradict the boundedness assumption.

Let $M$ be a bound of $y$. Then we notice that

1. Since $f$ is continuous and takes values only in $\Bbb{R}^+$, we have $\epsilon := \inf_{|x| \leq 2M} f(x) > 0$.
2. Choose a sufficiently small $\delta > 0$. (Effectively any $\delta < \min\{ \pi/2, M / 2\pi \}$ will work.) Then for any $n \in \Bbb{N}^+$ and for any $x$ satisfying $|x - n\pi| \leq \frac{\delta}{n}$, we have
   $$  |x \sin x|
   \leq |x| |x - n\pi| 
   \leq (n\pi + \tfrac{\delta}{n}) \cdot \tfrac{\delta}{n}
   \leq M $$
   and hence $|y + x\sin x| \leq 2M$.

From these observations we get a lower bound

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx}
&= f(y(x) + x \sin x) \\
&\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(y(x) + x\sin x) \mathbf{1}_{\{ |x - n\pi| \leq \delta / n \}} \\
&\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \epsilon \mathbf{1}_{\{ |x - n\pi| \leq \delta / n \}}.
\end{align*}

But integrating both sides from $0$ to $\infty$, we get

$$y(\infty) - f(0)
= \int_{0}^{\infty} y'(x) \, dx
\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2\epsilon\delta}{n} = \infty, $$

a contradiction.

---

**Addendum.** This argument seems to suggest that the term $x \sin x$ is a borderline case, in the sense that if it is replaced by $|x|^{\alpha}\sin x$ for $\alpha > 1$ then we may have bounded solutions. That said, any qualitative analysis which only uses uses oscillatory behavior of $x \sin x$ is not enough and we actually need some quantative estimate.

Heuristically, if $f$ decays sufficiently fast, then the term $|x|^{\alpha} \sin x$ escapes any bounded region in $\Bbb{R}$ so fast that contribution from that region is not large.

Here is a rough sketch of this argument: Consider $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ and the solution $y$ of

$$ y'(x) = f(y(x) + |x|^\alpha \sin x), \qquad y(0) = 0. $$

To analyze the behavior of $y$, define $\epsilon(x) = |x|^{-\alpha}y(x)$. Then for $x > 0$ we can write

$$y'(x) = \exp\{ -x^{\alpha} |\sin x + \epsilon(x)| \}. $$

In order to make use of this formula, we make several observations:

- Since $y$ grows at most linearly, we find that $\epsilon(x) = \mathcal{O}(x^{-\alpha+1})$ and $\epsilon'(x) = \mathcal{O}(x^{-\alpha})$.
- For large $x$, solutions of $\sin x + \epsilon(x) = 0$ are very close to $\pi\Bbb{Z}$. Labelling the nearest solution to $n\pi$ by $x_n$, we have $x_n = n\pi + o(1)$.
- For large $n$ and near $x = x_n$, we have $|\sin x + \epsilon(x)| = (1 + o(1))|x - x_n|$.

Thus roughly, for large $N$, small $\delta > 0$ and small $c > 0$ we have

\begin{align*}
y(\infty)
&= y(x_N-\delta)
+ \sum_{n \geq N} \int_{x_n - \delta}^{x_n + \delta} y'(x) \, dx
+ \sum_{n \geq N} \int_{x_n + \delta}^{x_{n+1} - \delta} y'(x) \, dx \\
&\lesssim 1
+ \sum_{n \geq N}^{\infty} \int_{x_n-\delta}^{x_n+\delta} e^{-c n^{\alpha} |x - x_n|} \, dx
+ \sum_{n \geq N} \int_{x_n + \delta}^{x_{n+1} - \delta} e^{-c n^{\alpha} \delta} \, dx \\
& \lesssim 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-c\delta n^{\alpha}}  < \infty.
\end{align*}

I think this can be turned into a rigorous argument by filling some missing details.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider what would happen if $y $ was bounded. That is
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}y=L<\infty$$
(If $y $ is bounded by $L $ that limit must exist since $y $ is monotonocally increasing). The next thing we know is that since $y $ is monotonocally increasing, the only way that $y $ can be bounded above is if $\lim_{x\to\infty}y'=0$. However this cannot be the case when $y $ is bounded by $L $. We have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(y+x\sin x)$$
And we know that since $f$ is continuous, we can say that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(y+x\sin x)=f(\lim_{x\to\infty}[y+x\sin x])=f(L+\lim_{x\to\infty}[x\sin x])$$
if $f$ isn't a constant function. And we know that that limit is undefined which leads us to our conclusion. Moreover, if $f=c$ and that limit equals $c$ we know that $c\neq 0$ because $f$ maps to positive real numbers.
(This makes since intuitively also: Since we know as $x \to \infty $, $y+x\sin x\to L+x\sin x $, the argument for $f $ oscillates at increasing amplitudes for large $x $. Moreover, since as $x\to\infty $ the amplitude of  the argument goes to infinity, which means the argument will oscillate over $f $'s entire domain, $f $ will oscillate over its entire range. That means the limit only exists if $f $ is a constant function, in which case the limit would be that constant.)
Since we have just shown that its impossible for $\lim_{x\to\infty}y'$ to equal zero when $y$ is bounded, it contradicts that fact that $y$ *can* be bounded. Thus $y $ cannot be bounded. And since it's monotonically increasing that means it must grow without bound.

Comment: The argument of $f$ definitely grows without bound, but that doesn't mean, even if $f$ is positive definite that $\lim_{\eta \rightarrow \infty} f(\eta) \neq 0$--$f$ could _very well_ approach zero--the problem is how fast does it approach zero (and clearly "how fast" doesn't matter in this question).

Comment: $f $ cannot approach zero though if the argument oscillates through all of $f $'s domain, which is what the argument does as $x\to \infty $. Infact it can't approach anything if that's the case unless $f $ is constant, and that constant has to be >0.

Comment: Does the following not approach zero even though it's argument oscillates?  $f(x) = \frac{1}{x\sin(x)}$

Comment: Thats argument doesn't oscillate, it's just $x $.

Comment: And that function's limit doesn't exist.

Comment: But that's the same thing as $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.  Then $f(x\sin(x))$ "oscillates" through its domain yet when plugged into $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ it converges to $0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Graph $g (x)=f (x\sin x)=\frac {1}{x\sin x} $ and you will see how the oscillating term make $\lim_{x\to\infty}g (x) $ undefined.

Comment: A $C^1$ function $y$ can be bounded and strictly monotone increasing yet its derivative may have train of bumps which prevents $y'(x) \nrightarrow 0$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x\sin(x)} = 0$.  Squeeze theorem: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$--these are the extremes--the maximum being $1$ and the minimum being $-1$.  Both of those functions converge to $0$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$ therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{x\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)} < \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x\sin(x)} < \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{x\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} \rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} -\frac{1}{x} < \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x\sin(x)} < \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: You are forgetting that everytime $\sin x $ gets close to 0, $\frac {1 }{x\sin x} goes to infinity.

Comment: @WillFisher You're right, that limit doesn't exist...

Comment: @WillFisher I am seeing now that your answer is very similar to mine--just said in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 0):

First off we need to show that the *only* possible way that $y$ is bounded is if $\lim_{\eta \rightarrow \infty}f(\eta) = 0$.  If the function $f$ doesn't approach zero then there is *no way* that $y$ is bounded (since it's derivative is always positive and thus grows always).  This should be "easy" to prove since if the derivative is positive definite and *never* zero then $y$ is monotonically increasing and *never* asymptotes (it can *only* asymptote if it's derivative approaches zero).

So from here on out we are only concerned with functions $f$ which approach zero at infinity.  Herein lies the problem (with a bounded solution) with the form of the function: $f(y + x\sin(x))$.  Consider that $x = n\pi$--in which $x\sin(x) = 0$.  We *require* that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(y + x\sin(x)) = 0$ to **possibly** be bounded, i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} y = b$, where $b > 0$.

At this point, it's *very* important to note that $f(x)$ is *only approaching* zero when it's *argument* is infinite--any other argument and it will *not* be infinite.  We can easily show that *if* $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} y(x) = b$, then for $x = n\pi$, $n\gg 1$, $f(y + xsin(x) \approx f(b + n\pi\sin(n\pi) = f(b)$.  But if $b$ is *finite*--not *infinite* then $f(b) \neq 0$ (no matter how large $b$ is because $f(x)$ is only zero in *the limit* that $x\rightarrow \infty$).

This result, that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(y + n\pi\sin(n\pi)) = f(b)\neq 0$ contradicts the *required* result that $f$ approaches zero as its argument approaches infinity.

Therefore, assuming that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} y = b$ results in a contradiction to the *conditions* for $y$ being bounded thus $y$ is *unbounded*!  My only reservations is in the significance of $y(0) = 0$--I'm not sure why that is necessary *or even* if it is.

**Caveat**

My proof is *not* rigorous because because I assume only $x\in\mathbb{N}$.  Indeed if $\lim_{\eta\rightarrow \infty} f(\eta) = 0$ then $f(x) = 0$ for $x \gg 1$ *except in the very special cases when* $x = n\pi$--you need to show that this "non-convergence" provides a contradiction even in the $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and I'm not totally sure how to that.